# Restore from dead letter queue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic, dead-letter

I receive all JMS messages from Queue1 all the time and trying to process it. 
 If I tried to process 5 times, and rolled back 5 times, I want ActiveMQ to put the message to a different queue for some period of time (e.g. 5 minutes).
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom property to the message - like RESUBMIT_TIMES, and increment that until 5 is reached. Read this : [JMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setIntProperty%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

if 5 is reached move it to the *5minutesqueue*, by setting another property there that has the current timestamp. For example:

```
  message.setStringProperty("TimeOfDispatch", LocalDate.now().toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss"));
```

Have yet another consumer on the *5minutesqueue* that check if 5 minutes have passed(by checking current time with the time from the header)

Comment: Thanks Eugene. It looks like I need to handle it from a client side, but the question is if I can handle moving a message that has JMSXDeliveryCount==5  from Queue1 to a Queue2 for a 5 minutes (afterwards move back to Queue1) on the side of ActiveMQ. Is it possible?

Comment: @surlac I do not know, but honestly I don't think that they have such a thing in place. It is up to you to code it

Comment: ActiveMQ has ["deadLetterStrategy"](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) configuration, it very close to what I need, but not exact match.